# Remove duplicates and put the list into a listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

This is an uni assignment and I am having problem with part of it. This is the code;

```
namespace Assignment_1
{
public partial class Classifier : System.Web.UI.Page // We are using a web form as stated
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // No variables are initiated for the beginning
    {

    }



    protected void ButtonClassify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.TextBox1.Text != "")
        {
            List<string> numbersText = this.TextBox1.Text.Split(',').ToList<string>();
            foreach (var item in numbersText)
            {
                int num = int.Parse(item);


                if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "Both") 
                {
                    if (num % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        if (CheckBoxDuplicate.Checked == true)
                        {
                            List<int> evenNumbers = new List<int>();
                            evenNumbers.Add(num);
                            List<int> distinctEvenNumbers = evenNumbers.Distinct().ToList();
                            ListBoxEvenNumbers.DataSource = distinctEvenNumbers;

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            //Put the results into the respective boxes
                            ListBoxEvenNumbers.Items.Add(num.ToString());
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Put the results into the respective boxes
                        ListBoxOddNumbers.Items.Add(num.ToString());
                    }
                }

                if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "Even")
                {
                    if (num % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        //Put the results into the respective boxes
                        ListBoxEvenNumbers.Items.Add(num.ToString());
                    }
                }

                if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "Odd")
                {
                    if (num % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        //Put the results into the respective boxes
                        ListBoxOddNumbers.Items.Add(num.ToString());
                    }
                }
```

Let me explain the question and what I have done. User inserts list of numbers into a text box and then has 3 options (radiolistbutton). He can list even, odd or both type of numbers. They display in even and odd listboxes(2 listboxes). I have done up to this part.

There is a checkbox to remove duplicates and the user can check it if he wishes to. If the button is checked, the code should remove the duplicates. I tried to do this part in the 4th "if-else" "if (CheckBoxDuplicate.Checked == true)". The way I understand it, I check if the number is even and then check the CheckboxDuplicate button. if it is checked I put the values in a new list and then delete repeated values. Then put into EvenNumbers listbox. For some reason, this part doesn't work.

If you would like to help me, please don't post just your answer. This is my first project in C# and it is difficult for me to understand an elegant solution yet. If you have time, please check my code and let me know where I made a mistake. Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: in your second part, you're just adding 1 number the evens? what are you doing there ? Also, check my answer to have a much more readable code for the above.

Comment: @Noctis: I give num value to items from numbersText list? Line9.
I am new to C#, my code is not elegant yet.

Comment: That's not your full code. Please update it.

Answer (score 1):

Sprinkle a bit of linq magic on it, and you're done.

```
var my_list = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7};

var pair = my_list.Where (n => n%2 ==0); // 2,4,6
var odd = my_list.Where (n => n%2 ==1);  // 1,3,5,5,7

var unique_pair = pair.Distinct(); // stays the same
var unique_odd = odd.Distinct();   // 1,3,5,7
```

From here is just adding it to your appropriate calls and GUI containers

---

From your comment, here are a couple of things:

1. Change the `if` to `if - else if`, since only one will apply.
2. you can do it the way you do, but it's not the most efficient. If you go that way, you'll have to figure out which numbers you've added in order to not have duplicates.
3. alternatively, you can simply create the lists like I've done in the code above, and then assign them at the end. It'll save you time and code.

---

Here's some more help, with no code, since I believe i covered it.

**Step 1**: get the user input, and create a list of ints. (call it: input_list).
**Step 2**: According to what he chose (even, odd, both), you want to assign to each listbox, a list of numbers. Look at my above code, it'll do that bit for you.
**Step 3**: If user choses unique, you pass to those listboxes the `Distinct` list, again, look at my above code for that.

You can apply the unique on the event of the checkbox being selected if you prefer.

Notes:
Keep the list of ints (the input_list) as a variable, so you don't need to parse it whenever he changes his selection.

Comment: Do you reckon, you can help me now?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will work on it. Sorry for the previous duplicate of question.

Answer (score -1):

```
public enum PairOddEnum
{
    Evens,
    Odds,
    Both
}

public void BindControl(PairOddEnum type)
{
        if (this.textBox1.Text != "")
        {
    List<string> numbersText = this.textBox1.Text.Split(',').ToList<string>();
    var evens = numbersText.Where(t => int.Parse(t) % 2 == 0).Distinct();
    var odds = numbersText.Where(t => int.Parse(t) % 2 == 1).Distinct();

    if (type == PairOddEnum.Evens)
    {
        ListBoxEvenNumbers.DataSource = evens.ToList();
    }
    else if (type == PairOddEnum.Odds)
    {
        ListBoxOddNumbers.DataSource = odds.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        ListBoxEvenNumbers.DataSource = evens.ToList();
        ListBoxOddNumbers.DataSource = odds.ToList();
    }

        }

}
protected void ButtonClassify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "Both") 
    {
        BindControl(PairOddEnum.Both);
    }

    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "Even")
    {
        BindControl(PairOddEnum.Evens);
    }

    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "Odd")
    {
        BindControl(PairOddEnum.Odds);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 `If you would like to help me, please don't post just your answer`