# sorting even numbers in a string then adding to a listbox

Tags: c#, arrays, string, listbox, append

Massive C#/Coding in general noob here.

I essentially want to sort the parity of a string of numbers users put into a textbox.
So, users put in "4,5,2,12,56,4,1234" into a textbox. I want it so they click a button to sort it into even and odd numbers, (even numbers go in ListBox1, and odds go in ListBox2). I'm not worried about error catching.

```
 public string sortParity()
{
    string userInput = TextBox1.Text;
    string[] numberArray = userInput.Split(',');
    foreach (string i in numberArray)
    {
       turn i into an int somehow
           if (i % 2 == 0){
               ListBox1.Items.Add(i);
           } else {
               ListBox2.Items.Add(i);
           }
    }
```

The thing is, I don't know how to test it and I'm unsure as to what is going to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Just to clarify, I want to know how I can turn the i into an integer.

Comment: I can't turn i into an integer, so I don't know.

Comment: [deja vu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25337117/1698987) . Duplicate most probably. Same assignment ... won't even search for it ... ?

Comment: int x = Int32.Parse(i);

Comment: I searched for hours before I asked the question. I'm clearly not very good at searching.

Comment: If your primary question is on how to convert strings into integers, it'd be more productive if you ask that question explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:-

```
        public string sortParity()
           {
              string userInput = TextBox1.Text;
              string[] numberArray = userInput.Split(',');
              foreach (string i in numberArray)
              {
               int x = Int32.Parse(i);

                 if (x % 2 == 0){
               ListBox1.Items.Add(x);
             } 
                else {
           ListBox2.Items.Add(x);
        }
          }
      }
```

Comment: this worked fantastically, thanks yash :)